# How to bind different input text value in each row in a Table using ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

Please developers in the house,
I have a table in my angular Application that am populating with a data from database and a row which is an input text field that I need to fill from FrontEnd and binding the Input text field using ngModel to be send to the database. But I observed that if I have three record in the table and I try typing in a value in one of the Input field, the other two input fields automatically get filled with the data am filling in one Input text field which I think is as a result of ngModel. Please how can i bind it so that the input number type in one input field will not be filled in other fields. Below is my code:
Thank you for your help.

```
 <tbody>
                                 <tr *ngFor = "let SelectItem of selectRequisition ; let i = index ">
                                <td style="width: 150px;">{{SelectItem.transactionDate |date}}</td>
                                   <td style="width: 150px;">{{SelectItem.description}} </td>
                                   <td style="width: 150px;"> {{SelectItem.remark}} </td>
                                   <td style="width: 150px;"><input type = "number" ngModel = "InputItem"></td>
                                 </tr>
                                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for you will be to add a property to your model and bind it to your input.
For example, with this model:

```
export interface MyItemModel { 
 transactionDate:number;    
 description:number;    
 remark:string; 
 SomeNumber:number; // <-- Add this property
}
```

You can bind the `SomeNumber` property to the input like this:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="SelectItem.SomeNumber">
```